# modifying a multiple selects validation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I've got so far:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/m4tyC/1/)

What I want is:

1. add class "invalid" for the `<select>` if it was not selected in it's row
2. remove this class if the 3 selects in the row are selected
3. if all `<select>`s in one row are selected then submit the form
4. if only one `<select>` is selected then add the "invalid" class to the other 2 selects in the same row

This is the HTML and the js is included in the fiddle link above :

```
 <form id="productOptions" name="product-options">
  <div class="selects s1">
    <select name="selectss1" id="size1" class="product-select-options-size">
      <option>-Size</option>
      <option>Small</option>
      <option>Medium</option>
      <option>Large</option>
      <option>X-large</option>
    </select>
    <select name="selectsc1" id="color1" class="product-select-options-color">
      <option>-Color</option>
      <option>Green</option>
      <option>Pink</option>
      <option>White</option>
      <option>Yellow</option>
    </select>
    <select name="selectsq1" id="qty1" class="product-select-options-qty">
      <option>-QTY</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects s2">
    <select name="selectss2" id="size2" class="product-select-options-size">
      <option>-Size</option>
      <option>Small</option>
      <option>Medium</option>
      <option>Large</option>
      <option>X-large</option>
    </select>
    <select name="selectsc2" id="color2" class="product-select-options-color">
      <option>-Color</option>
      <option>Green</option>
      <option>Pink</option>
      <option>White</option>
      <option>Yellow</option>
    </select>
    <select name="selectsq2" id="qty2" class="product-select-options-qty">
      <option>-QTY</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects s3">
    <select name="selectss3" id="size3" class="product-select-options-size">
      <option>-Size</option>
      <option>Small</option>
      <option>Medium</option>
      <option>Large</option>
      <option>X-large</option>
    </select>
    <select name="selectsc3" id="color3" class="product-select-options-color">
      <option>-Color</option>
      <option>Green</option>
      <option>Pink</option>
      <option>White</option>
      <option>Yellow</option>
    </select>
    <select name="selectsq3" id="qty3" class="product-select-options-qty">
      <option>-QTY</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <p><a href="#" class="add-more">+ Add more at one time</a></p>
  <!-- End select options -->
  <input type="image" name="product-options" src="/media/blackheart/images/blackheart/add-to-cart.png"  />
  </form>
```

Kindly advise

Comment: Can you rewrite your first paragraph-sentence? Perhaps break it up in steps?

Comment: @step #3: You should never automatically submit a form onchange, especially when it is one for selling items.

Comment: I fixed some formatting for you. Now it is clear what I (think) you want

Answer (score 0):

You posted the very obscure question. For instance, you did not say on what event "invalid" class has to be added/removed. I suppose that this is 'submit'.

Also you gave 4 conditions and #1, 2, 4 ones are redundant cause they are mutually exclusive to some degree. I.e. if you **add class "invalid" for the  if it was not selected in it's row** then what is the sense of **remove this class if the 3 selects in the row are selected** ? You have to *simply remove this class if it is selected*. Again, #4 condition is in essence the same as #1.

your js-code works well, you only must to add several lines to manipulate css-classes
Note: I did not use jsfiddle, I checked this code in real browser (including IE7) and it worked, whereas it didn't at jsfiddle.

```
$(function(){
    $('#frm_productOrder').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var f=$(this);    
        var invalid=false, selected=0;
        $('.selects').each(function(){
            var row=$(this);
            var items=0;
            $('select', row).each(function(){
                var t=$(this);
                var selectedIndex=t.prop("selectedIndex");
                if(selectedIndex)
                {
                    items++;
                    t.removeClass('invalid'); //this line was added
                }
                else t.addClass('invalid');    //this line was added
            });
            if(items==3) selected++;
            if(items>0 && items<3) invalid=true;
            items=0;
        });
        if(selected>0 && !invalid) f[0].submit();
        else alert('Please fill up the form correctly');       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution i wanted , thanks for all the help :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#formid').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var f=$(this);    
            var invalid=false, selected=0;
            $('.selects').each(function(){
                var row=$(this);
                var items=0;
                $('select', row).each(function(){
                    var t=$(this);
                    var selectedIndex=t.prop("selectedIndex");
                    if(selectedIndex)
                    {
                        items++;
                        t.removeClass('invalid'); //this line was added
                    }
                    else t.addClass('invalid');
                    $("#formid").find(".invalid").removeClass("invalid").filter(':lt(1)').addClass("invalid");
                        //this line was added
                });
                if(items==3) selected++;
                if(items>0 && items<3) invalid=true;
                items=0;
            });

        if(selected>0 && !invalid) f[0].submit();
        else {
        /*alert('Please fill up the form correctly');*/
        $(".selects-msg").slideDown();
        }

      });
    });
```